# How Do I Make My Music App ( MediaPlayer ) Work With External Equalizers like DSP Manager?

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, cyanogenmod

I'm currently working on an update for my music app, and I can't seem to make it compatible with external equalizers (specifically DSP Manager), similar to how Google Play Music and Apollo are. I've been Googling for the past hour but I can not seem to find anything. I think it may have something to do with my audio session id, but It did not seem to do anything.

This is how I initialize my Service that contains my MediaPlayer object, and help or tips are appreciated, thanks!

```
@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    // create the service
    super.onCreate();

    // create mediaplayer, set wake lock and
    bgmusic = new MediaPlayer();
    bgmusic.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    // No Wakelock might need it if music is dropping, dont forget to re-add
    // permission
    // bgmusic.setWakeMode(this.getApplicationContext(),
    // PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
    playList = new ArrayList<File>();
    index = 0;   
    volume = 1;
    fading = false;
    isPaused = false;
    loopBool = false;
}
```